# Why java useBean saying invalid class value?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, usebean

When trying to use a java bean in the jsp useBean attribute it's always generating errors like "invalid bean class"

For example:
<jsp:useBean id="myID" class="myPack.Myclass" />
But it still throws invalid class value Exception.

Comment: Does `myPack.Myclass` exist in your project/classpath? Do you need to import it as well? Have you taken a look at the documentation of `useBean`?

Comment: Yes i have, this is my project structure: myproject/myPack/Myclass

Comment: Does MyClass have a no-arguments constructor? And - is there any more information available except „invalid bean class“?

Comment: It have a no argument constructor but when I run the code it returns a HTTP 500 status saying the value of the used bean class attribute is invalid, the type of the error is exception report, description is: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request, that's the only thing it report.